# Why are my old URLs still called?

Tags: symfony, url, indexing, web

There is a website which I took down for a long time (almost 6 months). I refurbished the full website, it's all look and feel and everything in it (I even changed the framework from PHP Zend to Symfony3).

After launching on production, I activated the Symfony monolog reporting system to see what errors I am getting. With bunch of errors for sure, but they were all known and clear for me except for one.

> No route found at /some_old_route.

I am not sure whether it is Google reindexing the whole website with new URLs or what is exactly going on. Some old links are being called and causing a "no route found" problem which is more than 3000 errors all being reported in 2 days.

This is an example of the error from the server log file.

```
Error   69.30.213.82    404 GET /dienstleister/eco-express/9260 HTTP/1.0        Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+) 23.8 K  Apache access
```

Any thoughts?
And if it was Google, how to tell her that these URLs are gone now?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the log entry, this specific request was done by `MJ12bot`, whoever that is. If the bot works correctly it will remember that the URL is not available anymore and not try it again in the future.